# Apps Script Addon: How to track admin domain install?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-marketplace, google-apps-script-addon

I'm trying to get the list of emails of users who installed my addon.

I'm using the `onInstall` trigger to get the email and push it to my database.

This is fine with individual installation (normal gmail or even admin who chooses to Individual Install)

But with `Domain Install`, `onInstall` event was not fired

So how can I track the Domain Installation?

Comment: The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#add-on_events) specifies "when a user installs", so I don't think it will trigger on a domain install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the LicenseNotification endpoint of the G Suite Marketplace API:

https://developers.google.com/gsuite/marketplace/v2/reference/licenseNotification/list

The result will be something like this:

```
{
  "kind": "appsmarket#licenseNotificationList",
  "notifications": [
    {
      "kind": "appsmarket#licenseNotification",
      "id": "001566972002228000-000001",
      "applicationId": "xxx",
      "customerId": "test@gmail.com",
      "timestamp": "1566972001590",
      "provisions": [
        {
          "kind": "appsmarket#provisionNotification",
          "editionId": "default_edition",
          "seatCount": "1"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "kind": "appsmarket#licenseNotification",
      "id": "001568364120883000-000001",
      "applicationId": "xxx",
      "customerId": "domainabc.com",
      "timestamp": "1568364119585",
      "provisions": [
        {
          "kind": "appsmarket#provisionNotification",
          "editionId": "default_edition",
          "seatCount": "-1"
        }
      ]
    },
    ...
  ],
  "nextPageToken": "001569976724468000-000001"
}
```

Inside the `notifications` array, notice some object that has `"seatCount": "-1"`

Those are domain installations that we are looking for.

We just need to get the value inside `"customerId": "domainabc.com",`