# Know if addon is domain installed or as individual

Tags: google-apps-script

on for google workspace.
I want to handle my own licensing and allow admins to install both for the complete domain or as individual.

The problem is I can't find anywhere in the documentation how I would be able to get the information on how it was installed from inside the add-on.

There is a similar question here
[Apps Script Addon: How to track admin domain install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57943614/apps-script-addon-how-to-track-admin-domain-install)
But that seems like it's not meant to be used from inside the script.

Is there a way? - and in that case is there also a way to see how many users it was installed for if the user chose domain install.

Comment: Could you make the Marketplace API request using `UrlFetchApp()` in a separate web app and call it from inside your script?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure if this answers your question, but from within Apps Script you can use ScriptApp and [getInstallationSource](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#getInstallationSource()):

```
ScriptApp.getInstallationSource();
```

Which performs the following:

> Returns an enum value that indicates how the script came to be installed as an add-on for the current user (for example, whether the user installed it personally through the Chrome Web Store, or whether a domain administrator installed it for all users)

The [InstallationSource](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/installation-source) enum contains three values:

1. APPS_MARKETPLACE_DOMAIN_ADD_ON (Add-on was installed by the administrator for the user's domain)
2. NONE (Script is not running as an add-on.)
3. WEB_STORE_ADD_ON (Add-on was installed by the user from the Chrome Web Store.)

So, if you want to know if the application was installed as a domain add-on, you could call:

```
const isDomainAddon = ScriptApp.getInstallationSource() === ScriptApp.InstallationSource.APPS_MARKETPLACE_DOMAIN_ADD_ON;
```